# System solution

Tags: equation-solving

How to solve this system using *Mathematica*.

[image]

```
eq1 := xsin[y] - 3.5 cos[y] - 4.5;
eq2 := -xcos[y] - 3.5 sin[y] + .4;

Solve[eq1, eq2, {x, y}]
```

This does not work.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the Mathematica StackExchange! Have you tried `Solve`? The documentation is very helpful, with many examples.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Instead, post *Mathematica* code, properly formatted in code blocks (edit your post by clicking the grey edit button under your post, and click the grey question mark at the right of the toolbar for formatting help). We are neither a do-your-problem-for-you service nor a teach-you-how-to-use-Mathematica service, so please attempt a solution and ask a *specific* question about some bit of *Mathematica* that you are struggling with.

Answer (score 6):

Note the syntax!

```
eq1 = x Sin[y] - 3.5 Cos[y] - 4.5;
eq2 = -x Cos[y] - 3.5 Sin[y] + .4;

Solve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, y}]
(* {{x -> -2.85657, y -> -2.54573}, {x -> 2.85657, y -> 2.36842}} *)
```

or

```
eq1 = x Sin[y] - 7/2 Cos[y] - 9/2;
eq2 = -x Cos[y] - 7/2 Sin[y] + 4/10;

Solve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0}, {x, y}] /. C[1] -> 0
```

[image]